# Second app is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller, ng-app

Hi I am new to angular and I am trying to create 2 apps in a single HTML file but I am not getting the output for the second app and I am getting the proper output for the first app. Can anyone tell me where am I doing it wrong? The code is as below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>The example for angular</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
            <style>
                input.ng-invalid {
                    background-color: lightcyan;
                }
    
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-app="myApp">
                <div ng-controller="hello">
                    <p>{{firstname}}</p>
                </div>
                <div ng-init="Akshay=[
                            {firstname:'Sandeep',place:'mangalore'},
                    {firstname:'sirish', place:'haridwar'},
                    {firstname:'krish', place:'mathura'}]">
                    <div ng-repeat="name in Akshay">
                        {{name.firstname + ' ' + name.place}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ang"></div>
                <form name="myForm">
                    <input type="email" name="emaild" ng-model="text">
                    <span ng-show="myForm.emaild.$error.email">Please enter the proper email</span>
                </form>
                <input type="text" ng-model="mytext" required>
            </div>
    
            <div ng-app="Appname" ng-controller="personCtrl">
                <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
                <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
                <p>His firstname was{{firstName}}</p>
                <p>His second name was {{lastName}} </p>
                <h1> His name was {{fullname()}} </h1>
    
            </div>
            <script>
                var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
                app.controller("hello", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.firstname = "Akshay";
                });
                app.directive("ang", function () {
                    return {
                        restrict: "C",
                        template: "This is a great time to be alive"
                    };
                });
    
                var appsec = angular.module('Appname', []);
                appsec.controller("second", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.firstName = "Bhagath";
                    $scope.lastName = "Singh";
                    $scope.fullname = function () {
                        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
                    };
                });
    
    
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't bootstrap two module in single html file. According to Doc

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other

Answer (score 2):

you can use manual bootstrap method to bootstrap both the modules simultaneously

Modify the two boostrap lines to happen when the document is ready:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() { 
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app1'), ['app1']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app2'), ['app2']);
});
```

When modifying your plnkr in this way, both apps started working properly.

Live Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/samirshah1187/w7gv56t5/

Answer (score 0):

As @Samir said, we can use manual bootstrap method to bootstrap both the modules simultaneously we need to define id like this `<div ng-app="myApp" id="myId">` `<div ng-app="Appname" ng-controller="personCtrl" id="personId">`,

and then add these lines at the end inside script

`angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myId'), ['myApp']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('personId'), ['Appname']);`

we need to bootstrap the modules to have multiple ng-app within the same page.